# Secondary static binding fails

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Here is a nice example on static binding: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/binding-static-properties-in-wpf-4-5/

I'm trying to add a second one but it does not update. Only the first one, ApplicationTitle is updated.

The xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtApplicationTitle"  Text="{Binding Path=(local:AppSettingApproach1.ApplicationTitle), Mode=TwoWay,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtApplicationTitle2"  Text="{Binding Path=(local:AppSettingApproach1.ApplicationTitle2), Mode=TwoWay,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My class:

```
class AppSettingApproach1
{
    public static event EventHandler ApplicationTitleChanged;
    public static event EventHandler ApplicationTitleChanged2;

    private static string _applicationTitle;
    private static string _applicationTitle2;

    public static string ApplicationTitle
    {
        get { return _applicationTitle; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _applicationTitle)
            {
                _applicationTitle = value;
                if (ApplicationTitleChanged != null)
                    ApplicationTitleChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ApplicationTitle2
    {
        get { return _applicationTitle2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _applicationTitle2)
            {
                _applicationTitle2 = value;
                Console.Beep();
                if (ApplicationTitleChanged2 != null)
                    ApplicationTitleChanged2(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The startup class

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AppSettingApproach1.ApplicationTitle = @"Hello WPF, this my first Approach of static binding.";
    AppSettingApproach1.ApplicationTitle2 = @"Hello WPF, this my SECOND Approach of static binding.";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming convention for the static property changed event is `<PropertyName>Changed`, so

```
public static event EventHandler ApplicationTitleChanged2;
```

is a wrong name. It must be

```
public static event EventHandler ApplicationTitle2Changed;
```